# A matrix-free way to find a fan basis of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof

Let $f:V\to V$ be a linear map, $\dim V =n$. A basis $( v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$ such that for all $j=1, \ldots,n$ the space $\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ is $f$-invariant is called a **fan basis** of $V$ w.r.t. $f$. Clearly, a basis is a fan basis iff the transformation matrix of $f$ w.r.t. to it is upper-triangular.

One can show that $V$ has a fan basis w.r.t. $f$ iff the characteristic polynomial of $f$ can be completely factored into linear factors over $\mathbb K$. All the proofs seem to show it via induction which doesn't demonstrate what's going on. The worked out examples of triangulating a matrix aren't quite illuminating either since one jumps to the change of basis matrices and crops the transformation matrices in such a way that I can't see how can one put it in terms of the original map $f$.

Say, our $f$ has $k$ pairwise distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ and the characteristic polynomial of $f$ can be completely factored into linear factors. How do we find the fan basis $( v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$ w.r.t. $f$? (I am looking for a matrix-free explanation.)

I can start: take $v_1$ to be an eigenvector of $\lambda_1$.

**Edit**: I understand the Jordan normal form but finding the fan basis should be much easier, so I don't understand which parts of the Jordan procedure can be left out.

Comment: Take $v_i$ to be the $n$ generalised eigenvectors of $f$ grouped in a way that the low-order eigenvectors preceed the higher-order generalised EVs for the same (generalised) eigenvalue. This is equivalent to finding the Jordan normal form of $f$.

Comment: @AlexR: thanks for reminding me about Jordan, I should have mentioned it. I understand the Jordan normal form but finding the fan basis should be much easier, so I don't understand which parts of the Jordan procedure can be left out.

Comment: The Jordan procedure guarantees you that it will find a fan basis. Its lack of computational efficiency is caused by the fact that we get a very special fan basis since it allows us to completely classify $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get around finding generalised Eigenvectors of $f$, but for the first $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ you can chose the (usual) eigenvectors of $f$, since every eigenspace of $f$ is $f$-invariant. Now the next $f$-invariant spaces are precisely the generalised eigenspaces or direct sums thereof wich means you'll need to find $n-k$ generalised eigenvectors to get valid $v_i$ unless $f$ is diagonalisable (i.e. $k=n$).

Since the vectors in $\{v_i\}$ must always be generalised Eigenvectors, we can use a known fan basis to get the JNF of $f$ directly from it. This shows that finding a fan basis is equally difficult as finding the JNF. Note that to make this argument rigorous you need to see that the only $f$-invariant subspaces of $V$ are the direct sums of (generalised) Eigenspaces of arbitrary order.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the vectors in the fan basis must always be generalized eigenvectors? Say $B=(v_1,v_2)$ is a fan basis of $V$ w.r.t. $f$. Then $$[f]_B=\left(\begin{matrix}
        \lambda_1 & a \\
         & \lambda_2 \\
        \end{matrix}\right),$$
so assuming $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$ the set of generalized eigenvectors of $\lambda_2$ equals to $$\text{span}(v_2-\frac{a}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}v_1).$$ So $v_2$ is not in it (given $a\neq 0$).

Comment: @Leo But $v_2$ will be in the direct sum of the generalised eigenspaces of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Knowing this you can still find the JNF from $v_1, v_2$ in the way you just described. This leads me to the conclusion that they are computationally equivalent. I changed the wording of the specific part to better reflect this.

Comment: So you suggest to find a basis of $\text{Gen}(λ_j)$ by taking a basis of $\text{Ker}(f-λ_jI)$, expanding it to a basis of $\text{Ker}(f-λ_jI)^2$ and so on. If we put it together: $$[f]_B=\left(
\begin{matrix}
A_1 & & 0 \\
    & \ddots & \\
  0 & & A_k\\
\end{matrix}
\right) \text{with } A_j =\left(
\begin{matrix}
λ_1 & & * \\
    & \ddots & \\
  0 & & λ_k\\
\end{matrix}
\right). $$

That's indeed triangular and almost of good as JNF since by expanding the bases we have got all the info on the dimensions, so even though we don't have the Jordan basis we know exactly how the JNF looks like.

Comment: Is that what you mean?

But it's not what I meant. For example, my text gives a procedure how to find a fan basis. And the resulting matrix looks like this: $$[f]_B=\left(
\begin{matrix}
 4 & 3 & -4 & 2  \\
 0 & -2 & 28 & 4 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{matrix}
\right),$$

so the matrix doesn't resemble the one in the previous comment. And the alternative procedure looks easier than the Jordan-like one. I guess I should ask a new question, quote the procedure from my text and ask for clarification.

Comment: @Leo Yes your first comment is what I meant. I would be interested in this procedure and I'd like to see how it relates to finding the JNF. Maybe finding the JNF is just "hidden" in a convenient way.