# Fan basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find a fan basis for the linear maps of $\mathbb{C}^2$ represented by the matrices: a)$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$

**Solution**.(a) Clearly, the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue 0. Let $V_1$ be the space generated by this vector. Then $\{V_1,\mathbb{C}^2\}$ is a fan for the given linear map.
***Solution´s Manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra, Rami Shakarchi***.

**Fan basis definition**: By a fan basis we shall mean a basis $\{v_1,...v_n\}$ of V such that $\{v_1,...,v_i\}$ is a basis for $V_i$.***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang.***

***Questions:***

**1)** I may be misunderstanding the defintions I am studying. Since $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ generates a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$, then $\{V_1\mathbb{C}^2\}$ is a fan basis. Can I pick an arbitrary subspace? Why does the subspace needs to be generated by a basis that is an eigenvector?

**2)** If I multiply $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ by a negative scalar, it proves that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ does not generate a subspace. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

> **1)** I may be misunderstanding the defintions I am studying. Since $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ generates a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$, then $\{V_1\mathbb{C}^2\}$ is a fan basis. Can I pick an arbitrary subspace? Why does the subspace needs to be generated by a basis that is an eigenvector?

You're missing a key part of the definition of a **fan basis.** 
Let $~f:V\longrightarrow V~$ be a linear map, $\dim V =n$.

Definition: A basis $( v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$ such that for all $j=1, \ldots,n$ the space $\text{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ is $f$-invariant is called a **fan basis** of $V$ with respect to $f$. See: [A matrix-free way to find a fan basis of $V$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1050569) for where I clipped that text from.

From this definition, it would appear that you're missing a vector, namely $$v_2=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1
\end{array}
\right].$$

You should check that this is, in fact, an eigenvector with eigenvalue 2, and this should allow you to construct a fan basis for $\Bbb{C}^2,$ in agreement with the definition Leo has provided in the link.

> **2)** If I multiply $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ by a negative scalar, it proves that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ does not generate a subspace. Is this true?

No this is not true. Every vector generates a subspace via the "span" operation. In particular

$$\text{span}\left(\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}
\right]\right)=\left\{ \alpha \left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}
\right], \text{ where } \alpha \in \Bbb{C}\right\}=V_1.$$

You should verify that this is a subspace, and that for any negative scalar, say for example $-1,$ that $$-1\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
-1\\
1
\end{array}
\right]\in \text{span}\left(\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1
\end{array}
\right]\right).$$

Comment: The author has never referred that a fan basis needs to be $A$-invariant. The only occasion I used the  $A$-invariant was to prove that the inverse of $A$ has a fan basis .

Comment: I have been searching for fan basis definitions and unfortunately, I am not finding in the definition the fact the basis must be A-invariant.

Comment: Could you provide me other sources?